# drupal 6, merging two content types in a view(2.0) results

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I am building a site for research oriented company. and having problems showing fields from two different content-types into one view without duplicating node (titles).

To be specific. I have a content type called as 'Articles' where all the information like title, teaser, body, year, image will be stored.
and another content type by name "resource-links' where links (pdf attachments) will be linked along with file's author name. this content type is needed as I need one to many relationship here. One article has many links with different authors.

now in the second type 'Title' remains same (as it is required field, drupal).

When I created view and in the fields I am showing:
from type article': TItle, year, teaser
from type resource-links: author of file, link (pdf file)

filtering these on: content type, taxonomy term

in a result set I see fields from both cotent type with title repeating, I rather would want to merge fields from content type one and two based on the title and show it collectively.

LIke: Title of the article(appearing once), Year published, teaser.
links along with author name.
HOw to achieve this? any ideas...anybody worked on similar issue?
merging two views may help me but I don't know how to do that.

thanks,
Leena

Answer (score 0):

Node reference and views are dificult to get playing well together.

One way you may be able to get round this is to use display type of node, rather than fields, and then create a seperate node template which works well in your view.